# Compile less in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I want to customize the styles of tx_news, so I copied news-basics.less and news-basics.css into my site extension.

My environment is: TYPO3 9.5, Boostrap_package 11.0.2, tx_news 7.3.1

Now my question is what is the best practice to compile news-basics.less into news-basics.css? As bootstrap_package seems to include a scss compiler (maybe a less compiler too ?-), it would be nice to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Bootstrap Package includes a LESS compiler (but will be removed in 12.x).

Add e.g. the following lines to your setup TS and Bootstrap Package will compile it:

`page.includeCSS.news-basic = EXT:yoursitepackage/Resources/Public/Less/news-basic.less`

Comment: OK, that seems to work for now. I just was afraid of a conflict with tx-news' way of including css ($pageRenderer->addCssFile(...).

Answer (score 1):

The templates and css of news extension are not really meant to be fully ready for production sites. I propose to just create custom css and include that in your main css